# samba access denied: "session closed for user nobody"

Tags: samba, services, pam, cifs, file-sharing

I am seeking to add a Samba share to a host running Linux Mint.

Desired features of the share are discoverability of the host and share through broadcast, accessibility of   files only by users with accounts on the host (i.e. no guest or anonymous access), authentication through the same password used for regular system login, and enforcement of permissions for file access for each credentialed user the same as for local sessions.

I have added the following line to the tail end of `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[store]
comment = Storage
path = /srv/store
guest ok = no
writable = yes
privatable = no
browsable = yes
```

Unfortunately, the effect carries more than one difference from my objective.

First, I notice the host is not discoverable. Then, if I manually enter the host name, along with credentials, and attempt access, the attempt is rejected, and the following cryptic message enters the service log from the daemon (available through `systemctl status smbd`):

> `pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody`

What is the meaning of the message, and how may I discover and login to the host, as a Samba server?

Comment: What are you connecting from ?

Comment: @Rowland: I am connecting through the Samba client invoked by GVFS/FUSE running under Linux Mint.

Comment: gvfs has problems at the moment, which they do not seem to be trying to fix. You need SMBv1 for Network Browsing and the latest Samba has this turned off by default. Try using smbclient instead.

Comment: @Rowland: Would it help to use `client min protocol = NT1`?

Comment: You could, but you would also need 'server min protocol = NT1'. However, it would be better to get SMBv2 & SMBv3 working.

Comment: My preference is being able to use Gvfs as well as other clients (because of the convenience of the integration with graphical file managers). Using `client`/`server min protocol` helped with discoverability, but not authentication. Is there possilby some other problem. with the authentication setup, in SMB server or PAM? Why does the log report that access was attempted by user `nobody`.

Comment: Gvfs needs fixing, it relies on SMBv1 which is very, very insecure. Microsoft wants to remove it and Samba is working hard on removing it, so I do not recommend using it. If you must have your shares appearing in Explorer, then run a wsdd server on your Samba server, see here: https://github.com/christgau/wsdd

Comment: @Rowland: I was referring to accessing (and mounting) the shares through Linux file managers that use Gvfs, such as Nautilus or Nemo. Would wsdd be helpful for this use?

Comment: (But discovery is not the main issue. The main issue is authentication.)

Comment: @Rowland: I am still confused. Will wsdd help with authentication? Is there a way to solve the authentication issue, with or without wsdd??